# terminal freezing when interfacing gps module with raspberry pi

Tags: gps, raspberry-pi3

I am using raspberry pi 3 B+ with latest raspbian stretch. I am trying to interface **GPS module Neo 6m V2** with raspberry pi.Connected my raspberry pi with gps module using female to female jumper wires.

VCC to Pin 1, which is 3.3v

TX to Pin 10, which is RX (GPIO15)

RX to Pin 8, Which is TX (GPIO14)

Gnd to Pin 6, which is Gnd

I followed below steps to configure : ---

1. edit `sudo nano /boot/config.txt` , at the bottom of above files added two lines

   enable_uart=1

   dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
2. sudo rebbot
3. stop serial ttyS0 using command

   sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service
4. disable serial ttyS0 using command

   sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
5. sudo reboot
6. enable ttyAMA0 using command

   sudo systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
7. verify it using `ls -l /dev` ,it gives

   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           7 Sep  6 15:18 serial0 -> ttyAMA0
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           5 Sep  6 15:18 serial1 -> ttyS0
8. install minicom package using `sudo apt-get install minicom`
9. but when I am checking it using

   sudo minicom -D/dev/ttyAMA0 -b4800
   it freezes , nothing showing me on terminal.as shown below
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu64l.png)

Even `sudo cat /etc/ttyAMA0` ,also not showing anything.
Please help to solve this .as I am trying this project first time,I dont know much about this.
So what's wrong with freeze terminal problem??
how can I find out ,that my gps module is working or not?when I power on raspberry pi , gps module's red light gets on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe read page 11 of the datasheet https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/NEO-6_DataSheet_%28GPS.G6-HW-09005%29.pdf on the configuration of the `UART` with pins `CFG_COM0` and `CFG_COM1`  ( you change the baud rate by this and i do not know how you configured the module ... )

In https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=84610 is more information especially NMEA commands and also a similar problem ...